# Why my query using find() does not return any document?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to make a query on mongo to get all the documents with three conditions :
In python code I have a dynamic value  `type` which can be changed it can have different values. And I want to get all documents with `type` and that don't have field `delete` and `inappropriate`  undefined.

So I started like this, here I call it:

```
find_entry_based_on_url({"type": "Test"})
```

Here is the method that I defined :

```
def find_entry_based_on_url(self, query):
    docs = self.mongo.db[self.collection_name].find(query , {"delete": {'$exists': False}} , {"inappropriate": {'$exists': False}})
    return docs
```

This is not working it gives nothing ? Can you help me what is wrong?

Comment: Yes the syntax is wrong. That is all I can tell you now. If you need a working solution you should explain what you mean by *This is not working* Also consider to edit your question's title.

Comment: @user3100115 I tested it also in code and I tried some other ways in terminal but it gives nothing

Comment: what is `query` in your `find` method?  What is the error message? traceback?

Comment: When i call this function I give another query like a parameter for example like I explained when I called it  {"type": "Test"} is the query value @user3100115

Comment: Please don't delete your question after you got a correct answer. You should leave it for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong the second argument to `find` is a projection document. Also in PyMongo, documents are regular Python dictionary which mean that there are mutable thus you can add additional key to your query.

```
from copy import deepcopy #  You need to make a deepcopy of original query


def find_entry_based_on_url(self, query):        
    q = deepcopy(query)
    extra_keys = ['delete', 'inappropriate']
    for key in extra_keys:
        q[key]['$exists'] = False
    return self.mongo.db[self.collection_name].find(q)
```